# How to limit indentation in the tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, indentation

I try to limit the number of possible indentations in TinyMCE but I can't find an option to do them, do you have an idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE fires a variety of events as you work with the content.  If you want to stop someone from indenting the content you would have to capture the event that is triggered when someone clicks the indent button and decide the action you want to take.

Here are some examples of the types of code you can use to listen for events:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function (e) {
       editor.setContent('<p>This is the content in TinyMCE!</p>');
    });
    editor.on('init keydown change click blur', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('data').innerText = editor.getContent();
    });     
    editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
        console.log('ExecCommand:', e.command);
        if (e.command === "indent") {
            console.log('Someone clicked the indent key');  
        }
        if (e.command === "outdent") {
            console.log('Someone clicked the outdent key');  
        }
    });
    editor.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
        console.log('NodeChange event fired', e);
        console.log(editor.selection.getNode());

    });
    editor.on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('change event fired');
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows some of this sort of code in action:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/6fhaab/1

Once you know that someone clicked the indent/outdent these sorts of events give you access to the content that TinyMCE is about to modify and you can do what you need to modify or cancel the event.